# How can I set the permission of a .key file to be only accessed by nginx

Tags: linux, nginx

I have a SSL certificate key in the directory `/etc/nginx/key`, how can I set permissions to allow only the nginx process to access the key file?

Comment: Unless you use SE Linux, and take roots ability to edit SE policies (and/or disable SE all together) away you won't be able to stop root (or any process root runs) from accessing the file.

Answer (score 2):

Make the Nginx user own it, and then set the permissions to only owner like so:

```
chown /etc/nginx/key nginxUser
chmod 400 /etc/nginx/key
```

I chose 400 because no one should need to write to your key.  Note that root will still be able to read and write to this.  Also, replace nginxUser with the user that runs nginx, I don't know who that is off the top of my head.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do that, as root do the following:

```
chown nginx /etc/nginx/key
chmod 700 /etc/nginx/key
```